# How to make vertical line cutting through rows below header to appear above row color

Tags: tables

I want the vertical line between the two columns to appear above the color below header row. How can achieve that?

Thanks

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \mycaption[Shuaiba reservoir properties]{Shuaiba reservoir properties.}
    \label{table:chp2:sec02:Shuaiba reservoir properties}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Reservoir}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Dome-shape fractured carbonate}}
    \\ 
    \midrule
    \rowcolor{Gray}
    Matrix Porosity 
    & $\sim 30 \%$ \\ 
    Matrix Permeability 
    & 1 - 20 mD \\ 
    \rowcolor{Gray}
    Viscosity & 220 cp, $16^{\circ}$ API \\  
    Oil Saturation & $\sim 95 \%$ \\ 
    \rowcolor{Gray} 
    Gas Oil Ratio & $\sim 10\, sm^3/m^3$ \\  
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Add `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}` inside your table environment as discussed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168592/120578

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Much appreciation. Shall I delete this question since it is duplicate? @koleygr

Comment: It is better to leave it open and we will mark it as a duplicate. This way may help future visitors.